# Dynamically adding data to more TextView

Tags: android, xamarin, textview

Is it possible to dynamically add text to several textview that are defined in xalm? For example, in a loop:

```
var textView1 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
var textView2 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView2);
var textView3 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView3);

var content = "Add me to more at one textView"

for (i = 1; i = 3; i++)
{
// add me;
}
```

I can easily do it as it adds textview programmatically by calling GetChildAt () in layout. Is it possible to add dynamic if textView is defined in xalm?

Comment: `textView1.Text = "blah blah blah";`

Comment: I don't think I made myself clear. i know how to add text to textview. But I would like to do it in a loop. Let's say I have 30 textview. I would not like to list everyone one by one. Can it be done in a loop to shorten the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say your texts ids are text1, text2, tex3, etc. Use:

```
for (int i=1; i<numberOfTextsViews; i++) {
   int id = this.getResources().getIdentifier("text" + i, "id", getPackageName());
   TextView temp = findViewById(id);
   temp.setText("text you want to add to all your texts");
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I meant :D Could you rewrite t from java to c #?

Answer (score 0):

I write like this:

```
public TextView FindId(string resourceId)
    {
        var type = typeof(Resource.Id);
        var field = type.GetField(resourceId);
        int res = (int)field.GetRawConstantValue();

        TextView tx = FindViewById<TextView>(res);

        return tx;
    }
```

and:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 34; i++)
        {
            TextView tx = FindId($"textView_day{i}");
            tx.Text = day[i];
            tx.Tag = tx.Text;
            tx.Click += Day_Click;
        }
```

THX a lot Mike087 for getting me on the right track.